# Regarding recurrences, why do characteristic polynomials work, and why do we look for the roots?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots, intuition

I'll use an example recurrence but my question is meant to be generalized.

Let's say we had some recurrence, such as:

$$F(n) = -8F(n-1) + 9F(n-2) + 92F(n-3) - 140F(n-4)$$

where we already know the first few base constants $F(0), F(1), F(2), F(3)$ so the entire recurrence is defined for all integers $n \geq 0$.

Normally we convert this to some kind of *characteristic polynomial*:

$$x^n = -8 x^{n-1} + 9 x^{n-2} + 92 x^{n-3} - 140x^{n-4}$$

Divide everything by $x^{n-4}$ and put everything on one side:

$$x^4  +8 x^3 - 9 x^2 - 92 x + 140 = 0$$

This polynomial can be factored:

$$(x - 2)^2 (x + 5) (x + 7) = 0$$

And now we know that the roots are $2, -5, -7$. The $2$ root has multiplicity $2$, whereas the $-5$ and $-7$ roots each have multiplicity $1$.

From this we can say that:

$$F(n) = a  \cdot (2)^n + b \cdot n \cdot  (2)^n + c \cdot (-5)^n + d \cdot (-7)^n$$

And then we use the original four values of $F$ that we do know to solve a short system of equations and solve for $a, b, c, d$ to finish up the closed form.

The short version of my question is basically "Why does this work?"

Why can we use a "characteristic polynomial" (what is this, exactly) instead of a recurrence?

Why does that polynomial's roots directly correspond to the closed-form of that recurrence?

Why do we need to add an additional term with another power of $n$ for roots of multiplicity $>1$?

Comment: (This is more a sketch than a proper answer, so comment for now.) One way to see how the characteristic polynomial arises is to convert the recurrence $\{F_n\}$ into the generating function $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_n x^n$. You can show that $F(x)=A(x)/B(x)$ where $A(x)$ is a polynomial of low degree and $B(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial. The form of $F_n$ then follows from considering the partial fraction expansion of $A(x)/B(x)$.

Comment: Another way is to take "vector spaces" glasses. See for example (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/525791).

Comment: @Semiclassical Can you provide a more fleshed-out example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: First of all, it can be easily seen that $x^n$, where $x$ is a root, satisfies the recurrence-relation. Another property that can be easily shown is that the sum of two solutions is again a solution. The hard part is to show that there are no more solutions. To be honest, I have never seen a proof of this part. What is clear : If we fix the initial conditions, the solution must become unique. But another general solution with other constants could do the job as well. No idea how to rule this out.

Comment: @Peter We have very different definitions of "easily seen," haha. I don't see at all why $x^n$ must satisfy the relation, nor is it clear that the sum of two solutions is another solution (I'm less interested in this particular fact if it doesn't extend to higher-degree recurrences). I mostly just want to understand why characteristic polynomials work here, why the roots link to the closed-form, etc.

Comment: Just plug $x^n$ into the recurrence relation and divide the resulting equation by the power $x^k$ with the smallest exponent occuring (In your example, by $x^{n-4}$) .Bring all terms on one side. You get an equation of the form $p(x)=0$, the characteristic equation. If $x\ne 0$ is a root of this characteristic equation, $x^n$ must be a solution.

Comment: if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are solutions, just add the equations resulting from the recurrence relations for $a_n$ and $b_n$ to see that $a_n+b_n$ will be a solution as well. Finding the solutions in the case of multiple roots is harder.

Comment: @Peter I feel like this is exactly what I did in my post, but that doesn't tell me at all why it must be a solution (my entire question is asking why this polynomial "works")

Comment: @user438407 Not sure about this, I think there is a link to the linear differential euqations. The solutions of them have a similar structure, but I do not know exactly how to work out the analogy.

Answer (score 2):

Two explanations.

First, if you have $c_k a_{n + k} + \dotsb + c_0 a_n = 0$, a (not unreasonable, simple) idea is to try $a_n = \alpha^n$. Substituting, you get that it has to be $c_k \alpha^k + \dotsb + c_0 = 0$. Furthermore, the equation  is linear, i.e., multiplying a solution by a constant or adding two solutions gives a solution. If $\alpha$ is a multiple zero of the characteric equation, again trying $n \alpha^n$, $n^2 \alpha^n$, ... shows it "works".

A "more scientific" (can be extended in several directions) technique is to use generating functions: Define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, multiply the recurrence by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 1$, to get after recognizing some sums:

$\begin{align*}
c_k \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + k} z^n + \dotsb + c_0 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
  &= 0 \\
c_k \frac{A(z) - a_0 -a_1 z - \dotsb - a_{k - 1} z^{k - 1}}{z^k}
  + \dotsb + c_0 A(z)
  &= 0
\end{align*}$

If you now multipĺy this mess by $z^k$, and solve for $A(z)$, you get:

$\begin{align*}
A(z)
  &= \frac{p(z)}{c_k z^k + \dotsb + c_0}
\end{align*}$

here $p(z)$ is a polynomial. This in turn can be written as partial fractions,  the terms of which are of one of the forms, for some $r \ge 1$:

$\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{(1 - \alpha z)^r}
\end{equation*}$

You want the coefficients of $z^n$ in such. By the (extended) binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
(1 - \alpha z)^{-r}
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (-1)^n \binom{-r}{n} \alpha^r z^r \\
  &= \sum_{n \ge 0} \binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1} \alpha^r z^r
\end{align*}$

Note that the binomial coefficient $\binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1}$ is a polynomial of degree $r - 1$ in $n$, the $\alpha$ is seen to be a zero of the characteristic polynomial.