System of 2 recurrences where next term is sum of previous terms with a constant factor
I want to know how to find a closed form for the $n$-th term of
$$
M_{n+1} = M_n + cH_n\\
H_{n+1} = H_n + M_{n+1}
$$
For some constants $M_0 = m, H_0 = h, c$.

Motivation: I'm working on a game where houses $H$ are built by masons $M$, where more houses allow more masons to exist. That is, each mason builds one house while each house supports $c$ new masons$^{[1]}$. When the player opens up the game again, I want to calculate the number of new masons and houses given elapsed time $n$ since the game was last open. (To simulate game progress while it was turned off, as if it was never turned off.)
(The constants $m, h$ are integers but $c\lt 1$ is a rational. I'll round the final results $M_n, H_n$ to integers.)
$^{[1]}$ Each house actually supports $a$ new population and each mason requires materials for new houses. The material requirements translate to needing $b$ population to be distributed to gather appropriate resources, giving $c=a/b$.

Results: I have found a way to get the final result using Mathematica
RSolve[{a[n+1]==a[n]+c*b[n],b[n+1]==b[n]+a[n+1],a[0]==m,b[0]==h},{a[n],b[n]},n] // FullSimplify

which gives $M_n$
$$
2^{-n-1}(\sqrt{c+4})^{-1}\left(\sqrt{c+4}m\left(\left(c-\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n+\left(c+\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n\right)-\sqrt{c}\left(\left(c-\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n-\left(c+\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n\right)(2h-m)\right)
$$
and $H_n$
$$
2^{-n-1}(\sqrt{c}\sqrt{c+4})^{-1}\left(-\left(c-\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n(ch+2m)+\left(c+\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n(ch+2m)+\sqrt{c}\sqrt{c+4}h\left(c-\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n+\sqrt{c}\sqrt{c+4}h\left(c+\sqrt{c+4}\sqrt{c}+2\right)^n\right)
$$

Questions:

I am now curious how to derive these results on my own?



P.S.
As I'm writing this, I notice that in practice this grows exponentially and reaches $2^{64}$ (max integer size for my game variables) rather quickly. So perhaps, simply doing the iterations is sufficient and cleaner than a closed form solution (since max value is reached before $n$ gets large given my $c$). Also, the closed form solution would need to be rewritten to be numerically stable. I'm still curious about how to derive the final result on my own, nonetheless.

Hint…you can start by eliminating the $M$ terms to make a recurrence relation for the $H$ terms alone:
You have $$M_n=H_n-H_{n-1}$$
Therefore $$H_{n+1}-H_n=H_n-H_{n-1}+cH_n$$
Or, put more simply, $$H_{n+2}-(2+c)H_{n+1}+H_n=0$$
You can now go ahead and use the standard method for solving this - i.e. propose a solution of the form $$H_n=\lambda x^n$$
I hope this helps.

Ohh, so if I remember correctly now, this boils down to a characteristic polynomial? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2242305/1371752

@TinyTakinTeller  Yes, it does.

I guess you can finish it, right?
